# Not able to run periodically task with help of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

My application is launcher application i need to run periodically task so i wrote the code with help of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor but i noticed that some times it is working fine but some time it is not running i am not getting why it is happening. After restarting the device it is working fine but in some device it is not starting.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor_ = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor_.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new

                                             Runnable() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void run() {
                                                     try {
                                                         //Hitting an api
                                                     }
                                                 }catch(
                                                 Exception e)

                                                 {
                                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                                 }
                                             }
},10000,6000000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your version of Android, but if you want to periodically run a task regardless if the user has the app open or not, using the JobScheduler is usually better for the battery, although there are other options (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling). Ex:

```
        ((JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE)).schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(MY_JOB_ID, new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class))
            .setPeriodic(6000000)
        .build());
```

Then the code to call an API will be in the MyJobService class, onStartJob method.

Comment: Now i am using JobScheduler but it is not calling periodically, i am using android N and above version. please help

Comment: and one more problem is happening my job is starting but onStartJob is not calling

Comment: Check the return value of the "schedule" method and make sure it didn't fail, and it may not execute exactly at the interval to save on battery. Other than that, we might need your new code updated in your question.

Comment: it is returning 1.

Comment: ok i will update my question but could you suggest that if i want o hit api periodically then.